# python array indexing through function

Tags: python

I'm writing a function that will read a file given the number of header lines to skip and the number of footer lines to skip.

```
def LoadText(file, HeaderLinesToSkip, FooterLinesToSkip):
    fin = open(file)
    text = []
    for line in fin.readlines()[HeaderLinesToSkip, -FooterLinesToSkip]
        text.append(line.strip())
    return text
```

My problem is that this function will work properly only of FooterLinesToSkip is at least equal to 1. If FooterLinesToSkip = 0, then the function will return []. I can solve this problem with an if statement, but is there a much simpler form?

Edit : I actually simplified my problem; the lines read from the file contains columns separated by a semi-column. The real function includes .split(delimiter_character) and should store only column 1.

```
def LoadText(file, HeaderLinesToSkip, FooterLinesToSkip):
    fin = open(file)
    text = []
    for line in fin.readlines()[HeaderLinesToSkip, -FooterLinesToSkip]
        text.append(line.strip().split(';')[1])
    return text
```

Comment: You have a python `list`, not an `array`; there is a big difference between the types. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Set `FooterLinesToSkip` to `None` instead, so the slice defaults to the list length:

```
def LoadText(file, HeaderLinesToSkip, FooterLinesToSkip):
    with open(file) as fin:
        FooterLinesToSkip = -FooterLinesToSkip if FooterLinesToSkip else None
        text = []
        for line in fin.readlines()[HeaderLinesToSkip:FooterLinesToSkip]):
            text.append(line.strip().split(';')[1])
```

Let me offer you an improvement, which does not require you to read the whole list into memory:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

def skip_headers_and_footers(fh, header_skip, footer_skip):
    buffer = deque(islice(fh, header_skip, header_skip + footer_skip), footer_skip)
    for line in fh:
        yield buffer.popleft()
        buffer.append(line)
```

This reads lines one by one, after skipping `header_skip` lines, and keeping `footer_skip` lines in a buffer. By the time we looped over all lines in the file, `footer_skip` lines remain in the buffer and are ignored.

This is a generator function, so it'll yield lines in a loop:

```
with open(filename) as open_file:
    for line in skip_headers_and_footers(open_file, 2, 2):
        # do something with this line.
        line = line.strip()
```

I moved the file opening *out* of the function so that it can be used for other iterables too, not just files.

Now you can use the `csv` module to handle the column splitting and stripping:

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'rb') as open_file:
    reader = csv.reader(open_file, delimiter=';')
    for row in skip_headers_and_footers(reader, 2, 2):
        column = row[1]
```

and the `skip_headers_and_footers()` generator has skipped the first two rows for you and will never yield the last two rows either.

Comment: Not clearly understood your improvement. What are load_text and open_file? Also in your first solution why did you remove .strip()? Your solution with the 'with' statement puts the newline character is the yielded text.

Comment: @user1850133: I missed your `.strip()` call, for some reason. The second sample is more generic but I made an editing error. Mea culpa, corrected the sample.

Comment: In fact I simplified too much my example; I also need to split the lines as I edited in my original post.

Comment: You can do that too, sure. Is it not clear how to apply splitting to the output if the code in my answer?

Comment: I just want to return, say, column 1 of the read text. Of course once splitting is applied using, say, ';' as column separator.

Comment: @user1850133: Updated my first version to follow your code and the last sample to use the `csv` module to do the splitting. Note that your original question was solely about the `FooterLinesToSkip` parameter; we've gone a little beyond that here.

Comment: In the way my initial code was written I knew I just had to write "text.append(line.strip().split(';')[1])" to get what I wanted. But when I saw your solution I realised I simplified too much because in the way you wrote the code I couldn't figure out anymore how to extract only column 1 of my data.